# C program float f = 123.456;why f in memory is "123.456001"

Tags: c

C program float f = 123.456;why f in memory is "123.456001".

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    float f = 123.456;
    printf("%f**%10.2f**%.3f\n", f, f, f);
    printf("%f**%e**%g**\n", f, f, f);
}
```

123.456001

why 0.000001 ?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: It's not even 123.456001, but there are more decimals to come after the '1'.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary expansion of

```
123.456
```

is

```
1111011.0111010010111100011010100111111011111001110111...
```

The computer rounds this off to

```
1111011.01110100101111001
```

This is the number that is actually stored in the memory.

The decimal expansion of this number is

```
123.45600128173828125...
```

which was printed rounded off to

```
123.456001
```

Comment: I know it, but I can't understand. I know A\D or D\A; i can't understand why is 0.000001 in C program.

Comment: @kangear: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thks very much! I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Not every number can be represented exactly by a computer, that would require infinite memory. So floating point number are rounded to the nearest representable number.